# Detect no result return by search - Selectize.js

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Is there any way to detect empty search result when working with [Selectize.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js)?

If user types something and if they do not get the content from dropdown list, is there any way to detect the empty searches?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What would you like to happen with an empty search?

Comment: Suggest something else or log the empty searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Selectize.js` has an event called `onType`. When user type something, onType event will fire. You just need to register this event when you initialise the `Selectize.js`. Then, you have to count total results return by the filter.

Here is the implementation:

```
$('select[name=country_id]').selectize({
      // When user type something, onType event will fire.
      onType  : function(text) {
        if ( ! this.currentResults.items.length) {
          $('#country-not-found').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          $('#country-not-found').addClass('hide');
        }
      }
    });
```

For information please visit the following link:

https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#callbacks

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), selectize.js has an `onChange` event. You should be able to hook into that and check to see if the select list has any options or not. If not, you can run your "something else" code.

Check out the **City / State Selection** example in the link for more details on how to use the `onChange` event. Here is the demo's source code.

```
$select_state = $('#select-cities-state').selectize({
    onChange: function(value) {
        if (!value.length) return;
        select_city.disable();
        select_city.clearOptions();
        select_city.load(function(callback) {
            xhr && xhr.abort();
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.corsproxy.com/api.sba.gov/geodata/primary_city_links_for_state_of/' + value + '.json',
                success: function(results) {
                    select_city.enable();
                    callback(results);
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```